# Can't read from stdout until terminated

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

```
bash = require('child_process').spawn '/bin/bash', []
console.log 'Spawned bash as pid ' + bash.pid
bash.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stdout.write data
```

I'd expect that the code above would read from bash and display to the process stdout. It doesn't. If I replace `/bin/bash` with `/bin/bash -c /bin/ls` I will get the output of `ls` which I'd expect. Obviously this has something to do with `bash` remaining open.

Any hints on how to read what `bash` outputs without having to have the process terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/

It works like a charm!